# Fixture object reference incorrect in functional test

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, functional-testing, liiptestfixturesbundle

A functional test class relies on an object reference created in a fixture. The reference's id, however, is not identical to the object's id property as returned by the entity manager. Below is a test that demonstrates this problem.

Notes:

1. The error is the same when using `$this->setReference(...)` as when
   using the `public const ...` and `$this->addReference(...)`.
2. The object reference used in the test appears to be the next
   available id for nonprofit entities.
3. The test class was created after the error was observed in a more general test class.
4. The error is the same whether or not the fixtures are loaded before
   running the test class.
5. The application uses Symfony 5.1.2 with all dependencies updated.

Test class:

```
namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Liip\TestFixturesBundle\Test\FixturesTrait;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class ReferenceTest extends WebTestCase
{

    use FixturesTrait;

    public function setup(): void {
        $this->client = $this->createClient();

        $this->fixtures = $this->loadFixtures([
                    'App\DataFixtures\Test\OptionsFixture',
                    'App\DataFixtures\Test\NonprofitFixture',
                    'App\DataFixtures\Test\OpportunityFixture',
                    'App\DataFixtures\Test\UserFixture',
                ])
                ->getReferenceRepository();
        $this->client->followRedirects();

        $kernel = self::bootKernel();

        $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()
                ->get('doctrine')
                ->getManager('test');
    }

    public function testNonprofitReference() {
        $npo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(\App\Entity\Nonprofit::class)
                ->findOneBy(['orgname' => 'Marmot Fund']);
        $nId = $npo->getId();
        $id = $this->fixtures->getReference('npo')->getId();

        $this->assertEquals($nId, $id, 'Reference incorrect');
    }   
}
```

Test result:

```
Reference incorrect
Failed asserting that 4 matches expected 1.
```

NonprofitFixture (other fixtures may not be relevant):

```
namespace App\DataFixtures\Test;

use App\Entity\Nonprofit;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\ORMFixtureInterface;

class NonprofitFixture extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ORMFixtureInterface
{

    public const NPO_REFERENCE = 'npo';

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager) {
        $npo = new Nonprofit();
        $npo->setOrgname('Marmot Fund');
        $npo->setEin('123456789');
        $npo->setActive(false);
//        $this->setReference('npo', $npo);
        $this->addReference(self::NPO_REFERENCE, $npo);

        $npo1 = new Nonprofit();
        $npo1->setOrgname('Turkey Fund');
        $npo1->setEin('321654978');
        $npo1->setActive(true);
        $npo1->setWebsite('http://turkeysRUs.bogus.info');

        $npo3 = new Nonprofit();
        $npo3->setOrgname('Talk Trash Fund');
        $npo3->setEin('978654321');
        $npo3->setActive(true);
        $npo3->setWebsite('http://ttrash.bogus.info');

        $staff = $this->getReference(UserFixture::STAFF_REFERENCE);
        $npo->setStaff($staff);
        
        $opp = $this->getReference(OpportunityFixture::OPP_REFERENCE);
        $opp1 = $this->getReference(OpportunityFixture::OPP1_REFERENCE);
        $npo1->addOpportunity($opp);
        $npo3->addOpportunity($opp1);

        $manager->persist($npo);
        $manager->persist($npo1);
        $manager->persist($npo3);

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder() {
        return 5; // the order in which fixtures will be loaded
    }

}
```

framework.yaml excerpt:

```
liip_test_fixtures:
    keep_database_and_schema: true
    cache_db:
        sqlite: liip_test_fixtures.services_database_backup.sqlite
```

dama_doctrine_test_bundle.yaml:

```
dama_doctrine_test:
    enable_static_connection: true
    enable_static_meta_data_cache: true
    enable_static_query_cache: true
```

csv export from app.db:

```
"id","orgName"
"1","Marmot Fund"
"2","Turkey Fund"
"3","Talk Trash Fund"
```

Comment: my first guess would be, that *another* Marmot Fund is inserted with id 4 and removed after the test, while the fixtures bundle restores the old db after the test. ... but that's just a guess. my second guess is - since setup is run for every test method in the test class - that another test run causes this before the db is reset.

Comment: And what's your question about this? Loading fixtures before each test is pretty time consuming - why not do this once and use something like https://packagist.org/packages/dama/doctrine-test-bundle to ensure that your fixture data does not change?

Comment: If fixtures are not loaded references are not available. The alternative is to load the container to get an entity manager. Is that the only way around the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, such as it is, is that references have no place in a functional test. Their use is really a shortcut for clicking on links or taking some other action. A better test is to use the crawler to mimic the action.